# How to fix bound sparql query not working as expected?

Tags: if-statement, sparql, bind, triplestore, blazegraph

I have this sparql query that I need to modify. I have the example instance, which has the exampleID 12345. For this case, if the :hasRelatedExample connection exists, the ?test variable will become 2. If the :hasRelatedExample connection doesn't exist from the example instance, the ?test variable doesn't get assigned the 1 value as it should. How could I fix this query to reflect the needed behavior?

```
PREFIX : <http://www.example.com#>
Select distinct  ?test 
  where
  {
?ex a :Example ;
     :exampleID "12345" ;
     :hasRelatedExample ?relatedExample .

BIND (IF(BOUND(?relatedExample),2,1) as ?test)
}
```

Comment: you have to put the triple pattern into an `OPTIONAL`, i.e. `?ex  :hasRelatedExample ?relatedExample .` to allow for absence of the data

Comment: alternatively, use `exists` operator and omit the triple pattern: `PREFIX : <http://www.example.com#>
Select distinct  ?test 
  where
  {
?ex a :Example ;
     :exampleID "12345" .

BIND (IF(EXISTS {?ex  :hasRelatedExample ?relatedExample}, 2, 1) as ?test)
} `